# Foundation - Dropdown within dropdown

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

Using Foundation 5, I am trying to have a dropdown within a dropdown...

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1" data-options="is_hover:true" >More</a>
<ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
    <li><a href="#">Modify</a></li>
    <li class="has-dropdown" ><a href="#">Share</a>
        <ul class="dropdown" >
            <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

But without any success!
The `Share` menu, is always displaying under the `Modify` menu.

***EDIT 1***

I tried something else, it's better but not good enough:

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1" data-options="is_hover:true" >More</a>
<ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
    <li><a href="#">Modify</a></li>
      <li ><a data-dropdown="drop2"  href="#"  >Share</a>
          <ul id="drop2" class="f-dropdown content " data-dropdown-content  >
              <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
          </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

And added to my .css:

```
    .f-dropdown.content {display: block;}
```

Here is my full css: http://pastebin.com/QPaFbenF with the previous line at line 67

But when clicking on `Share`, the `More` menu disapear and I have to put my mouse over the `More` link to get the the `More` menu and his sub-menu `Share` displayed.

I have found this question on the zurb forum : [dropdown within dropdown](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/1294-dropdown-within-dropdown) and tried the answers, without any success :S

Comment: So you want to display Share menu next to Modify Menu?

Comment: @JanakaRRajapaksha I am not very sure what you mean by "next" but I just want the following architecture:  More->Modify-Share->(This a link - This is another- Yet another).   `More` is a dropdown menu, and `Share` is another dropdown menu inside the `More` dropdown menu....

Comment: I guess Modify and Share will be placed horizontally or vertically?

Comment: @JanakaRRajapaksha vertically yes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.f-dropdown.content` will do nothing since you do not have a class named content under `f-dropdown class`

These should be in your CSS:

```css
.has-dropdown ul {
  display: none;
}
.has-dropdown:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7WuV/)

Comment: I tried your answer, but without any success... I tried other ideas but without more success --> see my edit 1

Comment: I updated the answer with working example. If you can give your css codes, i can help

Comment: i can't see any that can be conflict with my given css codes in your css. did you check with the updated answer?

Comment: I just did what you wrote in your working example, and it's perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Nested dropdown menus tend to get complicated when you start from scratch. I would always recommend to start with [superfish](https://github.com/joeldbirch/superfish/). You can a see a working demo here: http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/examples/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I realised I simply didn't include the jQuery trigger to get all the dropdown etc elements via the dropdown.js file working.

```
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```